# Convert my Normal Internet into WIFI for my Android/iPhone Devices

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-wifi

I have a normal ADSL Modem which is connected to my Telephone Landline and this is the current internet source scenario that I have.

I was thinking of buying a WIFI Modem, but I found another option :
"802.11N Mini Wireless N 11n Wi-Fi Nano USB Wi-Fi Adapter Dongle WiFi"

This is cheaper alternative to buying a WIFI modem

I need to know if it would be possible to transmit the internet I am getting on my machine through this? I would use a software like a Virtual WIFI Manager (saw on youtube)

Answer (score 1):

You can have your PC run as a router while also using it as a computer. However, wireless routers are very inexpensive these days (used, $10) so to avoid the hassle, I would instead adding a wireless router.

NOW

---phone cable to wall---[DSL Modem]===ethernet===PC

AFTER

---phone cable to wall---[DSL Modem]===ethernet==={Wifi Router}===ethernet===PC

The router should do WPA or WPA security; if it only does WEP, get something else as WEP is not very secure.